# Macro app script traer datos siguiente fila

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estaba intentando crear una macro que me mostrara el siguiente resultado de una validación de datos (como si abriera la lista y seleccionara el siguiente dato) después de mucho marear, he decidido hacer una macro, que cuando toque el botón me busque el valor de celda Clientes!A3, en Listas!A89:A, y me traiga el dato de la siguiente fila a la misma celda.
He logrado hacerlo anteriormente si pongo un dato como Id (un numero de celda, e incluso una que sume a ese valor un +1 y me busque ese resultado, pero esto ya no lo logro, copio código(`he probado con getValue/s y setValue/s):

```
function BuscarCliente() { 
    var valorCliente = "Clientes!A3"; 
    var rangoLista = "listas!A89:A"; 
    var filaCliente = buscarFila(valorCliente, rangoLista); //Buscar la fila del cliente  
    var filaSiguiente = filaCliente + 1; //Obtener la fila siguiente a la del cliente  
    var datoSiguienteFila = obtenerDatoFila(filaSiguiente, rangoLista); //Obtener el dato de la siguiente fila  
    return datoSiguienteFila;  };


//Función para buscar la fila de un valor en un rango  

function buscarFila(valor, rangoLista) {  
    var data = rangoLista.getValues(); //Obtener los valores del rango 
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { if (data[i][0] === valor) {  
    return i + 1; // Retornar la fila del valor encontrado } }  
    return -1; //Retornar -1 si no se encuentra el valor };  
//Función para obtener el dato de una fila  

function obtenerDatoFila(fila, rangoLista) {  
var data = rangoLista.getValues(); // Obtener los valores del rango  
if (fila < data.length) {  return data[fila][0]; //Retornar el dato de la fila } 
return ""; //Retornar vacío si la fila está fuera del rango

  };
```